# ReactJS Uncaught ReferenceError: onSubmit is not defined

Tags: reactjs

Please help me to understand where I am doing what mistake? I created CustomerForm React Component, which having few form fields. These form fields will add records and in another component will show records into table format.

Every thing is working fine for CustomerForm React Component, but if I am adding onSubmit function than form fields are not loading and I am getting console error as:-

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: onSubmit is not defined
at new CustomerForm (index.js:32590)


<button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={ e => this.onSubmit(e)} > Submit </button>
```

Also please suggest any better way to write ReactJS code using Props & State...

```html
// Let's import react for creating component
import React from "react";

// Create CustomerForm component
class CustomerForm extends React.Component{
    
        // create constructor function for CustomerForm component
        constructor(props){
            
            // call super, so constructor function can connect with CustomerForm component
            super(props);
    
                // Use state add object with their property and value
                this.state = {
                
                    firstName : "",
                    lastName : "",
                    phoneNo : "",
                    issue : "",
    
                }
    
                // Create changeData function
                // changeData = e => {
                //     this.setState({
                //         [e.target.name] : e.target.value
                //     });
                // };
    
                onSubmit = e => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    console.log(this.state);
                }
    
        } // close constructor function
    
        render(){
            return(
                <form>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="fname">First name</label>
                        <input 
                            type="text"  
                            className="form-control" 
                            id="fname" 
                            placeholder="First name"                        
                            value={this.state.firstName}
                            onChange={e => this.setState({ firstName: e.target.value })}
                            />
                            {/* call setState for change firstName value 
                                question - I created changeData function which target name attribute and change value for form fields, but it's not working
                                onChange={e => this.changeData(e)}
                            */}
                    </div>
    
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="lname">Last name</label>
                        <input 
                            type="text"  
                            className="form-control" 
                            id="lname" 
                            placeholder="Last name"
                            value={this.state.lastName} 
                            onChange={e => this.setState({ lastName: e.target.value })}
                            />
                            {/* call setState for change lastName value */}
                    </div>
    
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="phone">Phone no.</label>
                        <input 
                            type="text" 
                            className="form-control" 
                            id="phone" 
                            placeholder="Phone no."
                            value={this.state.phoneNo}  
                            onChange={e => this.setState({phoneNo: e.target.value})}
                            />
                            {/* call setState for change phoneNo value */}
                    </div>
    
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="issue">Issue</label>
                        <textarea  
                            className="form-control" 
                            id="issue" 
                            rows="3"
                            value={this.state.issue} 
                            onChange={e => this.setState({issue: e.target.value})}
                            >
                            {/* call setState for change issue value */}
    
                        </textarea>
                    </div>
    
                    <button 
                        type="submit" 
                        className="btn btn-primary"
                        onClick={ e => this.onSubmit(e)}
                        >
                            Submit
                        </button>
    
                </form>
            );
        }
    
    }
    
export default CustomerForm;
```

Comment: Either take `onSubmit` out of constructor (preferable) or use `this.onSubmit = e => { ...` inside constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring a variable named `onSubmit` on the constructor and trying to access it with `this.onSubmit`, like a property.

You can do this in your constructor:

```
this.onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state);
}
```

**The suggestion**

A better way to accomplish this is extracting your `onSubmit` method to a class method, with makes your code more readable and more consistent. Would be something like this:

```
// Let's import react for creating component
import React from "react";

// Create CustomerForm component
class CustomerForm extends React.Component{
    // create constructor function for CustomerForm component
    constructor(props){
        // call super, so constructor function can connect with CustomerForm component
        super(props);
        // Use state add object with their property and value
        this.state = {
            firstName : "",
            lastName : "",
            phoneNo : "",
            issue : "",
        }    
    }

    /////////
    /// Your submit handler is now a method in the CustomerForm class,
    /// so you can access with the keyword "this"
    onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state);
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <form onSubmit={e => this.onSubmit(e)}>
             {/* Note that I've changed your handler to form,
                is usually better than put on a button, since you're using a form already */}
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="fname">First name</label>
                    <input 
                        type="text"  
                        className="form-control" 
                        id="fname" 
                        placeholder="First name"                        
                        value={this.state.firstName}
                        onChange={e => this.setState({ firstName: e.target.value })}
                        />
                        {/* call setState for change firstName value 
                            question - I created changeData function which target name attribute and change value for form fields, but it's not working
                            onChange={e => this.changeData(e)}
                        */}
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="lname">Last name</label>
                    <input 
                        type="text"  
                        className="form-control" 
                        id="lname" 
                        placeholder="Last name"
                        value={this.state.lastName} 
                        onChange={e => this.setState({ lastName: e.target.value })}
                        />
                        {/* call setState for change lastName value */}
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="phone">Phone no.</label>
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        className="form-control" 
                        id="phone" 
                        placeholder="Phone no."
                        value={this.state.phoneNo}  
                        onChange={e => this.setState({phoneNo: e.target.value})}
                        />
                        {/* call setState for change phoneNo value */}
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="issue">Issue</label>
                    <textarea  
                        className="form-control" 
                        id="issue" 
                        rows="3"
                        value={this.state.issue} 
                        onChange={e => this.setState({issue: e.target.value})}
                        >
                        {/* call setState for change issue value */}

                    </textarea>
                </div>

                <button 
                    type="submit" 
                    className="btn btn-primary"
                    >
                        Submit
                    </button>

            </form>
        );
    }

}

export default CustomerForm;
```

**Controlled Components**
Just one more thing I think it may be helpful to you (I've noted your comment about changeData) so if you not resolve the way to do controlled inputs, this minimalist example may help you, with a `onChangeHandler` I usually use:

import React from 'react';

```
export default class MyControlledComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        // Initiating the first value for our controlled component
        this.state = {
            name: ""
        }
    }

    submitHandler(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('Hi, ' + this.state.name + '!');
    }

    onChangeHandler(e) {
        const { name, value } = e.target
        /*
            Here we using the name property of your input to
            increase reuse of this function 
         */
        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        });
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div className="my-app">
                <form onSubmit={e => this.submitHandler(e)}>
                    <input type="text"
                        name="name"
                        value={this.state.name}
                        onChange={e => this.onChangeHandler(e)} />
                    <button>Send!</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I think you may need to bind `onSubmit()` in the constructor, or else you can't call `this.onSubmit()` later on.

Comment: Actually not, since we're using an arrow function. Arrow function have no proper context, so is executed in the parent context, in this case, our app (just like we want). Would be needed to bind in the constructor if we want to just pass the function like `myProp={this.myFunction}`.

Answer (score 0):

Your onSubmit function is not bind either bind it in constructor or use fat arrow properly like
`{(return)=>{functionname()}}`